# Where can I replenish my tank ammo?

Tags: planetside-2

I ran out of tank ammo. Where can I replenish it?

Comment: If we are creating the tag, we should be removing ALL the other tags; there's no need for mmo or fps.

Comment: @fbueckert Sure, feel free to remove them. I found [this on meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-tag-should-be-used-for-mmo-questions) - hence the tags. Either way is fine though.

Comment: That's two years old at this point. :P  We've changed how tags are used since then.

Answer (score 20):

Drive next to a **Sunderer infantry transporter** (see below) or **ammo supply tower** to replenish your ammo. This will also repair any damage on your vehicle.

*An ammo supply tower. Watch out for the holo-icon on the top. These are easy to miss since the HUD icon blends in nicely with the top, which makes them look like regular, non-usable world objects. The HUD icon is also slightly misleading - if you don't have a direct line of sight you may think this is an aircraft supply station.*

[image: ammo tower photo]

Note that not all Sunderers can resupply your ammo: only ones with "Vehicle ammo dispenser" in their loadout. A Sunderer with this feature equipped has the same holo-icon as the ammo tower on its sides, and on its minimap icon. The Sunderer *doesn't* need to be deployed or even stationary to resupply you.

Comment: This will not repair damage. Only replenishes ammo. Tried with Magrider in Vanu owned base.

Answer (score 1):

The **AMMO Sunderer** also resupplies vehicles. Notice the same holographic icon as the ammo tower on the side. Notice the model has ammo boxes, the holographic icon may not show up with some graphic settings.

[image]